# UDP listening socket on a multi-homed machine

Tags: c++, sockets, mfc, udp, winsock

We're listening for UDP traffic in a Win32/MFC application.  The listening socket is created using the below.

```
CSocket sock;
sock.Create(LISTEN_PORT,SOCK_DGRAM);
```

We call CAsyncSocket::ReceiveFrom() in a loop in a worker thread to allow receipt of packets in our app.

There appear to be issues when on a machine with multiple network cards.  For example, 2 wired networks, and one wireless adhoc network.  With this configuration, we don't seem to be receiving UDP data sent to our machine from a peer on the wireless adhoc network.

In contrast, we ARE able to send UDP to that same peer.  So its figuring out how to get traffic to the wireless adhoc peer, but traffic coming from the peer isn't getting to our socket.

My suspicion is that its because the machine is multi-homed.  My first thought was to make sure we're binding a UDP socket on all network interfaces.  However, I checked the CSocket::Create documentation and it indicates that if you use the default value of NULL for the third argument (lpszSocketAddress) that it will listen on all network interfaces.

So now I'm stumped.  Anyone know if there's a trick to listen for UDP traffic on a multi-homed machine that I'm missing?  Does the adhoc wireless network introduce any complications?

Comment: Did you checked to which ip the socket was bound really? (Eg. with TcpView from http://sysinternals.com or netstat.)

Comment: ah, I hadn't thought of that.  If I run that on my machine (not multi-homed), I get 0.0.0.0:MYPORT.  Does the 0.0.0.0 imply its bound to all interfaces?

Comment: Yes, 0.0.0.0 usually means bind to "any interface". But does any mean bind to all or does it mean pick "any" and bind to it, I don't know.

Comment: @Nerdtron: 0.0.0.0 means INADDR_ANY, ie a wildcard that means all interfaces.

Comment: @mtahmed: binding to 0.0.0.0 binds to "all" interfaces.

Comment: @Nerdtron: is the wireless network using IPv4 or IPv6? You are binding an IPv4 address. You need separate listening sockets for each protocol, unless you use a dual-stack socket (an IPv6 socket that supports IPv4 connections), which was introduced in Vista: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513665.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for the replies!  This is using IPv4 only.

Comment: I verified that on the multihomed machine, running netstat shows the socket listening on 0.0.0.0:MYPORT.  I'm going to check for firewall settings maybe.  We can send traffic out on the machine, just not receive it via UDP on that socket apparently.

Comment: Does a network trace with wireshark show the UDP packets on the wireless network? Maybe it's not a problem of your application but a network configuration problem? Also: is the wireless network using the same IP network as one of the ethernet cards (for example connecting to the same router wired and wireless).

Comment: I do realize this is a 6+ years old question (with no answer), but have it been resolved?  IMHO, I suspect it is receiving from all 3 interfaces, it is just that because you're bound to INADDR_ANY, the kernel cannot assume where/which NIC it came from, so it biases towards the priority of default gateway metric.  And if if metric are all the same, it biases towards the first NIC.  Some daemons like rpcbind/portmapper explicitly requires you to bind to NIC instead (i.e. 10.9.8.0/24 and 10.9.10.0/24) to resolve this issues.